# OnClick event of button fires everytime on PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

I have a button below:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnApprove_Click" />
```

Event handler of this button on server side is :

```
 protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", "alert('Button Approve Clicked')", true);      
    }
```

Just get alert on the button click from the server side.

My issue is that once I clicked on Approve button, now when I load or refresh my page again this `btnApprove_Click` event gets executed everytime.

I have many others button on the same form but none shows this strange kind of behaviour. I tried to change this button as HTML but still the same behaviour.

Can anyone please help me to get out of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of showing `alert`, use `Respone.Write("SOME_TEXT")` and report the result

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are experiencing but if you click the button and then hit refresh on the browser the page will be posted again (= button clicked again), most browsers ask for a confirmation about this though.

Comment: @Esko: Yes I am experiencing the same kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `IsPostBack` on Page load to prevent every time page load on button click. You can check every time on `Page_Load`.

**Sample Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         // First Time Load When User Come 
    }
    else
    {
       // Every Time Load When Any click button in page
    }
```

Comment: I have already this If condition implemented on my page, but this is not my concern. My concern is that once I clicked on the button(Approve) after that click event of Approve button called every time on Page Load  logically it should not.

Comment: When you click button then First go on Page_Load, then after render button click event. For more details you can read Page Life Cycle.

Comment: You can't avoid Page_Load on any control click event. It is sequence of page cycle.

Comment: I don't want to avoid page_load. I just wants to avoid click event of my button on page load. Why the click event of button fires even though I have not clicked on the button. This is my concern.

Comment: I got it. You mean every time when Page is load that time automatically your button click event is calling.

Comment: Yes exactly what's happening.

Comment: are you use btnApprove_Click(null, null); in page load or not ?

Comment: how can you refresh your page ? If you are refresh page using F5 then button event automatically fires. So avoid this fires, you can refresh your page from URL.

Comment: Yes..you are right..this is something very strange I noticed today..I was refreshing my page using ctrl+F5. I still don't understand that why the event of that particular button gets fired as I said I have many other buttons on the same page and no one gets fired on refresh. And if someone is working on jquery on the same page and he needs to hard refresh the page using ctrl+F5 it means all the functionality gets exexuted that we define on click events????

Comment: Have you any confusion regarding this ?

Comment: Yes..I don't actually understands the logic. I am not sure on the fact that F5 causes event click fire.

Comment: When you press F5 then your page is already in POST condition. so it reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Add `OnClientClick="return false;"`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnApprove_Click" OnClientClick="return false;"/>
```

Comment: Using the above approach I am unable to call Server side code(OnClick).

Comment: You are using `asp:Button` which is a server control, i think that is creating a problem, can you try with `input type="button"`

Comment: Already tried, <input type="submit" runat="server" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" class="button" onserverclick="ButtonApprove_Click" onclick="return Validate('Approve');"  value="Approve" />. I have used type="submit" because I need to call server side event.Same behaviour.

Comment: @GarvitGupta, This may helpful to you [Detect Browser Refresh and avoid Events fire in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Detect-Browser-Refresh-and-avoid-Events-fire-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `RegisterOnSubmitStatement` instead?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Page.GetType(), "key", "alert('Button Approve Clicked')");
```